# Parentheses off the page stop being recognized

Tags: indentation, macvim

I am using a recorded macro to manually wrap an extremely long string in a python script, like this:

```
blah = ('blahblah ... blah blah')
```

to

```
blah = ('blahblah...'
        'blahblah...'
        ...
        'blahblah...')
```

the macro is `4f,a''^[i^M^[`

This works fine, preserving my indentation right up to the point that the first line `blah =...` reaches the top of the page, then suddenly it starts dedenting to the first character of the line.  How can I prevent this?  i.e., how can I make vim recognize that the opening paren is above the top of the page?

EDIT: OK, it's not the top of the page, but 50 lines above, and my window (at present) is 52 lines.

Comment: I don't understand your macro. Specifically, the `4f,` part; this jumps to the fourth comma, but your example string doesn't have any commas. You should probably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/1325/51).

Comment: Give :set autoindent before trying macro. It works for me.

Comment: Give :set autoindent before trying macro. It works for me.